# Are there any stories with awkward first-time sex scenes between adults?

Tags: research, sex

I know first-time sex scenes between adults do exist in the literature, but are there any stories with awkward first-time moments? By "adults", I am referring to the mid-to-late 20s or early 30s age group or married couples regardless of actual age (may be as young as 16 years old).

This question is similar to the other question about [researching something you don't know](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/21592/how-to-write-about-what-you-dont-know), and that something is sex.

The sex scene may be relevant to the story, because it reveals how naïve the protagonist is when it comes to sexual intercourse. Both partners have no prior sexual experience. And the author, who also has no sexual experience, attempts to write such a scenario.

Alternatively, perhaps another way around it is to write the aftermath. That is, the failed sex attempt does not result in pregnancy. The couple tries again and again. One year passes, and the female is still not pregnant.

In a case like this, I don't think conducting an interview will work. First of all, how would one find the target population (married couples with both partners not having prior sexual experience)? Second of all, would they even be willing to share their first-time sexual experience?

Comment: I know of a visual novel with *multiple* awkward first-time sex scenes, but it doesn't fit your "mid-20s or married couple" requirement.

Comment: You're looking for such stories, in order to understand how to write your own? I suggest that instead of asking what existing stories to read, you simply ask here "I want to write a sex scene, but I don't have the experience I'd need for it". I think that'll be more helpful to you :)

Comment: What about implying the sexscene happened rather then actually describing it and then focussing on each of the characters emotions? That would save you a lot of trouble

Comment: Yes, there are many. Are you asking for a list? I'm not sure that would be on topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of two books which may help you. The first doesn't actually have any sex in it but it's the most perfect characterisation of a socially awkward, sexually inexperienced adult I've ever read and could inspire you in your character development. And that's:

[Eleanor Oliphant is Completely Fine by Gail Honeyman](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Eleanor-Oliphant-Completely-Fine-Bestseller/dp/0008172145/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1531825649&sr=8-1&keywords=eleanor%20oliphant%20is%20completely%20fine%20by%20gail%20honeyman)

The second is:

[On Chesil Beach by Ian McEwan](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Chesil-Beach-Ian-McEwan/dp/178470556X/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1531825678&sr=1-1&keywords=on%20chesil%20beach%20book)

This is the first night of a newly-married couple who have no sexual experience. The sex scene is awkward, bumpy and detailed and the combination of their individual inexperience and inability to express their thoughts works against each other to create the worst possible outcome. It's just brilliant.

I think the combination of these two books would really help inspire you to create your characters and scenes.

Good luck!

Comment: Okay, I reserved the books. Going to check them out.

Comment: @DoubleU Great, I hope they offer some inspiration. There's a wonderful audiobook of Eleanor if you can get your hands on that. The performance is outstanding. Best of luck with yours.